# Exibir resultados da pesquisa MySQL de acordo com a sequência mostrada na cláusula in

Tags: mysql, query

Como fazer para ordenar os resultados de uma query conforme sequência exibida na cláusula In? Ou seja, a ordenação das linhas deve respeitar a mesma ordem de valores indicados nesta cláusula.

Exemplo:

```
sql = select var_valor from tabela where var_codigo in (4,2,7);
```

Neste caso, o resultado deveria exibir primeiro o var_valor do código 4, depois do código 2 e por ultimo codigo 7.

Segue abaixo o código no SQL Fiddle para ilustrar a minha dúvida:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c663e/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `ORDER BY FIELD()`, assim:

```
sql = select var_valor from tabela where var_codigo in (4,2,7)
order by FIELD(var_codigo, 4,2,7);
```

No caso do exemplo que postou no SQL Fiddle, ficaria assim:

```
select con_valor as valor from tabela where con_variavel in ('corpo','rodape','exibesoma')
order by FIELD(con_variavel, 'corpo','rodape','exibesoma');
```

Leia esta documentação para saber mais sobre a função [FIELD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: Obrigado Murilo!!!